# Clojure - Function that returns all integers up to a certain number

Tags: clojure

I want to create a function that when you input a number say 5 it'll return a vector of all numbers from 1 to 5, ie [1 2 3 4 5]

So far I am at

```
    (defn counter [number]
      (let [x 1
            result []]
       (when (<= x number)
        (conj result x)
        (inc x))))
```

Right now it'll put 1 into the vector but I want to say now `(inc x)` and run through again. Do I have to use recur?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `(range 1 (inc number))` or, to get a vector `(vec (range ...))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a builtin function `range`. To achieve your goal (vector of numbers from 1 to n inclusively) you can wrap it as follows:

```
(defn get-range [n]
  (->> n inc (range 1) vec))

(get-range 5)
#=> [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Also, you can go and use `iterate` function

```
(defn get-range [n]
  (->> (iterate inc 1)
       (take n)
       vec))
```

Or use a loop:

```
(defn get-range [n]
  (loop [m 1
         res []]
    (if (> m n)
      res
      (recur (inc m) (conj res m)))))
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers from @fl00r are fine, but I wanted to throw in a reducible one as well:

```
(defn get-range [n]  ;; range/into
  (into [] (range 1 n)))
```

Reducibles are a better fit for this use case because

- `range` was rebuilt in Clojure 1.7 to be self-reducible, AND for the special case of long start/step/end values, it will use primitive longs during self reduction.
- Using the into transducer form means that the final vector can be built directly, rather than building a lazy sequence and then putting it into a vector
- `into` will automatically use transients when building the vector - there is a small overhead (compared to the loop approach) for very small ranges, but a big savings on larger ranges
- Because you are building a concrete collection (a vector), there is no benefit from laziness, so an eager approach makes more sense
- This approach is far more time and memory efficient than any of the sequence approaches. `range` as a reducible will consume no heap space (just a few locals). The transient vector is built by filling up arrays and then directly building persistent vector nodes as needed. By comparison, all of the sequence approaches will do boxed math on the iterator, build multiple nested cached sequence values, then copy those values one by one into a vector. The loop approach used above will use primitive math and obtains some of the perf benefits (but still has the downside of adding elements one-by-one to the vector vs transients).

Quick perf test (for vectors of various sizes):

```
Size |     range/vec |   iterate/vec |    loop/recur |   loop/recur' | range/into    |
-----|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
   1 | 160.968880 ns | 180.287974 ns |  40.373079 ns |  79.203722 ns | 136.157046 ns |
  10 | 378.058753 ns | 851.381372 ns | 342.720391 ns | 200.658997 ns | 253.015756 ns |
 100 |   2.486726 µs |   8.034826 µs |   3.464423 µs |   1.471333 µs |   1.760118 µs |
1000 |  23.349414 µs |  88.188242 µs |  37.247193 µs |  16.443044 µs |  17.109882 µs |
```

*Perf tests were done with Criterium quick-bench on Java 1.8/Clojure 1.8*

Versions tested:

- range/vec - 1st example from @fl00r - primitive math, 1 sequence, transients
- iterate/vec - 2nd example from @fl00r - boxed math, 2 sequences, transients
- loop/recur - 3nd example from @fl00r - primitive math, 0 sequences, no transients
- loop/recur' - same as prior, but modified to use transients - primitive math, 0 sequences, transients
- range/into - the example at the top of this answer - primitive math, 0 sequences, transients

Note that both of the last two have similar characteristics but loop/recur' uses a lot more code:

```
(defn get-range [n]   ;; loop/recur'
  (loop [m 1
         res (transient [])]
    (if (> m n)
      (persistent! res)
      (recur (inc m) (conj! res m)))))
```

Comment: awesome! Thank you!